# Should an adverb go before or after a verb?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order, syntactic-analysis, adverb-position

For example:

> The word **rarely** turns up outside of those contexts.
>
> The word turns up **rarely** outside of those contexts.

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: Rarely, the word turns up outside of those contexts. The word turns up outside of those contexts rarely.

Comment: The word turns rarely up for Yoda.

Comment: There's a big difference between main verbs and auxiliary verbs with regard to adverb placement, among other things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both correct, I don't think it's supposed to be limited here. Maybe the creative usage "turns rarely up" would also be used in some cases.

Comment: "turns rarely up" could be uncomfortable for a phrasal verb in the sense of appearing, but perhaps more reasonable in a prepositional verb in the sense of changing direction

Answer (score 17):

Positioning adverbs is a complex affair. There are [some rules of thumb](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv202.shtml), but for many adverbs, it is quite acceptable to place it before or after the verb. In this case, I think either way is acceptable, though I would probably find the former more natural, i.e.

> The word rarely turns up outside of those contexts.

but the following is also acceptable, if a bit less natural:

> The word turns up rarely outside of those contexts.

Two side notes: a) you want `those` (the plural of `that`), since `contexts` is plural, b) `of` is required in both cases here, as it belongs with the word `outside`.

Comment: Or, of course, just change "contexts" to "context".

Comment: @Mark Hurd: Yes, though I think it's much more likely he made the mistake with the adjective rather than the noun. :)

Answer (score 3):

Frequency adverbs such as *rarely* go before the verb or divide the verb phrase, as in "I have seldom seen such outrageous behavior." Other examples of frequency adverbs are *seldom, occasionally, often, sometimes*.

Answer (score 1):

In the first version, the word "rarely" seems to be the subject, rather than "The word," so the meaning is ambiguous.

As in:

The word "rarely" turns up outside of those contexts.

Answer (score 0):

"Turns up rarely" appears to describe the way it turns up rather than how often.
"Rarely turns up" shows how often.

Comment: They both describe the way it turns up — being adverbs attached to the verb phrase "shows up" — and in both cases that relates to how often.