# Adverbs right after the subject

Tags: adverbs, word-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should an adverb go before or after a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/should-an-adverb-go-before-or-after-a-verb)

Is it correct to write a sentence this way?

> Now we can speak about the steps that I’ve **previously** listed.

Or it would be better move the temporal adverb to the end?

> Now we can speak about the steps that I’ve listed **previously**.

Comment: Strictly personal preference. Mine is your first sentence. It's normal in English for modifiers to come before the words they modify, not after, except for a few adjectives (viz., _galore_) and adverbs (but misplacing adverbs can sometimes confuse the reader).

Comment: Try *yesterday* in place of *previously*.

Comment: Even with a different temporal adverb: We came early. *We early came.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are ok, but the second one sounds a bit better and may be used more in casual speech.

Comment: See what I mean about personal preference? There are no real answers about usage, just "I like this better than that".

Comment: My doubt is related with past tense and adverbs of frequency. I write `I've NEVER eaten snails` and probably it confuses me :P and I supposed it was a good idea to use any adverb type with this rule.

Comment: @MatterGoal: One should be as specific as possible when asking questions. There's no difference in meaning between "I've NEVER eaten snails" and "I NEVER have eaten snails", but they have different focuses and would be used in different contexts. Other placements of NEVER are not idiomatic, except in **contrived contexts**. "I NEVER ate snails" doesn't mean the same thing. It suggests that you won't eat snails because there aren't any more to eat or because you're about to die or to begin a liquid or vegan diet. Also, _never_ is a negative, not an adverb of manner.