# Word-Order "now" and "to be calculated"

Tags: word-order

Is it

> The process *now can* be calculated just like in the book.

or

> The process *can now* be calculated just like in the book.

?

Best regards (and feel free to edit if I missed something)

Comment: I think either is acceptable.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/should-an-adverb-go-before-or-after-a-verb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases, it's acceptable to place an adverb such as *now* before or after the verb it modifies. (See [this page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv202.shtml) for a good summary of the issue.) For this specific construction, [*can now* is used much more often than *now can*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+now%2Cnow+can&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20now%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnow%20can%3B%2Cc0), the latter of which is unusual enough that it can inhibit understanding in some cases. In fact, when I read your first sentence I initially interpreted it as saying that there is a process called "now" and that this process can (at some indefinite time) be calculated like it is in the book. So go with *can now*.

Comment: _Now_, like many adverbs, can appear either directly before the constituent it modifies, **or** directly before the beginning of a larger constituent that **contains** the constituent it modifies (in this case the Verb Phrase _can be calculated,_ as opposed to the VP _be calculated_). See the [VP guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) for details.