# 'normally' adverb placement

Tags: adverb-position

Which phrase is correct?

A will normally be finished by the end of the week, or, A will be normally finished by the end of the week.

The meaning I'm trying to convey is that if nothing abnormal happens, A will be finished by the end of the week.

I think it's the first, but I cannot explain a colleague why. Thanks!

Comment: Putting the adverb next to the verb in this case puts emphasis on the verb: "normally finished" would make the audience think there is something about the finishing that is "normal"—not that the entire process is usual or customary, as they would with "normally be finished."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should an adverb go before or after a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/should-an-adverb-go-before-or-after-a-verb)

Comment: Welcome to SE/EL&U! What would it look like to be _normally finished_ vs. _strangely finished_ or _abnormally finished_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say

> Normally, *A* would be finished by the end of the week.

(A conditional should be used since the outcome is not clear.)

> *A* would normally be finished [...]

is correct, since you are implying that, under normal circumstances, *A* would be finished.

Your other sentence implies *A* will be finished normally, i.e. *A* will be finished in a normal fashion by [...]

I hope this clears things up a bit.