# Difference and usage of "contains exclusively" vs "exclusively contains"

Tags: meaning, differences, phrase-meaning

Since the late 1800s, the phrase "contains exclusively" has been consistently used more often than "exclusively contains". [Ngram viewer: "contains exclusively" vs "exclusively contains"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contains+exclusively%2C+exclusively+contains).

What is the difference, if any?

Comment: _Exclusively_ means _to the exclusion of others_, so if we say that something 'contains exclusively (only)' a particular type of ingredient, it seems to me that _exclusively_ describes the range of ingredients, not the way they are contained. In other words, _exclusively contains_ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Positioning of adverbs is a complex matter, and depends on various factors including identifying the function of the adverb, and other factors around type of verb, general structure, readability, ambiguity, etc; with an abverb like "exclusively" whose category is less obvious, it's tricky. Here are questions from ELU and ELL SEs. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/should-an-adverb-go-before-or-after-a-verb https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/where-is-the-correct-place-to-place-adverbs-in-sentences