# Outside my control or outside "of" my control

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Outside” or “outside of”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9700/outside-or-outside-of)

Do we need "of" preposition in this expression?

> The defeat was certainly less glorious and vastly outside my control.

> The defeat was certainly less glorious and vastly outside **of** my control.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is necessary in that situation.  If you were to say, "He's standing right outside my window,"  that would make sense, as it's tangible  things that are being dealt with.

The same goes for "All of those people."

"All those people" would work if it was the answer to a question, but not otherwise.