# Should this sentence use 'of' or not?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, british-english

Here is a sentence:

> The major forces outside **of** the organization that have the potential to significantly influence the likely success of the products and services.

Is the use of the bold 'of' right in the above sentence?

Comment: Marked as duplicate, in short,  it's more common in American English.  I have seen and used it in 'British English' though, so it wouldn't cause a great stir if you did.

Comment: That's not a sentence!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is acceptable, especially in American English. Arguably, however, omitting the *of* would be more standard and universally acceptable.

**Two preliminary remarks**

1. As Hot Licks has commented, your example would not normally be considered a 'sentence', because it lacks a finite verb. Rather, what you have written is a [noun phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase).
2. As JeffUK has commented, the question is indeed a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9700/outside-or-outside-of).

**As far as grammar**

From [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), p. 639:

> *Outside* takes *of* rather than an NP [noun phrase] when the meaning is 
>   "except" (*Outside of us two, no one knew what was going on*), but with the locative sense *of* is again restricted to AmE (<sup>%</sup>*outside of Boston*).

**In published literature**

Both phrasings are widespread in published literature, e.g.

*Unfortunately, little systematic advice is available on how to choose a competent OD professional, whether from inside or o̲u̲t̲s̲i̲d̲e̲ ̲o̲f̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲o̲r̲g̲a̲n̲i̲z̲a̲t̲i̲o̲n̲.*

*An internal auditor may face the dilemma of considering whether to communicate the information to persons o̲u̲t̲s̲i̲d̲e̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲n̲o̲r̲m̲a̲l̲ ̲c̲h̲a̲i̲n̲ ̲o̲f̲ ̲c̲o̲m̲m̲a̲n̲d̲ or even o̲u̲t̲s̲i̲d̲e̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲o̲r̲g̲a̲n̲i̲z̲a̲t̲i̲o̲n̲.*

**In usage manuals**

Usage manuals traditionally recommend omitting the *of*. Thus [Garner's Modern American Usage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195161912) says

> **outside of** is inferior to *outside*—e.g.: "Italian goods have done well *outside of* [read *outside*] the Continent because the lira has fallen 15% vs. the U.S. dollar in the past year." ... When *outside of* appears in the sense *apart from* or *aside from*, either of those phrases would be more serviceable—e.g.: "*Outside of* [read *Apart from* or *Aside from*] economies of scale in purchasing and merged back-room operations, Pillowtex reaps Fieldcrest's well-known brands in sheets, comforters, [and] towels."

Similarly, [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/outside) says the following:

> *Outside of* tends to be more commonly used in the US than in Britain, where *outside* usually suffices, but, like its cousin *off of*, it is colloquial and not recommended for formal writing.  The adverb *outside* is not problematic when referring to physical space, position, etc. (*I'm going outside*), but the compound preposition *outside of* is often used as a colloquial (and often inferior) way of saying *except for*, *other than*, *apart from* (*outside of what I just mentioned, I can't think of any reason not to*). Besides possibly sounding more informal than desired, *outside of* may cause misunderstanding by suggesting physical space or location when that is not the point to be emphasized, or when no such sense is intended—consider the ambiguity in this sentence: *outside of China, he has few interests*. Does this mean that his primary interest is China? Or does it mean that whenever he is not in China, he has few interests?